# Texture ASTextNode border and shadow attributes do not work

Tags: ios, textures, asyncdisplaykit

Here is my code, I put one `ASTextNode` on my super view and applied some attributes, but some of them do not work, such as `ASTextBorder`.

```
    CGFloat top = 10;
    CGFloat bottom = -1;
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, -10, bottom, -10);
    CGFloat radius = font.pointSize / 2;
    mps.alignment = textAlignment; //NSMutableParagraphStyle


    ASTextNode *textNode = [ASTextNode new];
    ASTextBorder *asBorder = [ASTextBorder borderWithFillColor:UIColor.redColor cornerRadius:radius];
    asBorder.insets = insets;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor,
                                 NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                 NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: @(-5),
                                 NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor,
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: mps,
                                 ASTextBorderAttributeName: asBorder,
                                 };
    textNode.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
    textNode.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 5, 10);
    return textNode;
```

The rest of the attributes specified in the dictionary perform normal.

Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the custom attributes are available in ASTextNode2 and controlled by switch.